# Not getting POST method request parameters

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, post

I have a simple jsp POST form that submits two parameters username and password to another jsp. This was for test purposes.I get null when sending POST request. I get the parameters when I do GET. Is there any way that POST is getting disabled?
I am just running on tomcat.

Comment: You need to explicitly set method="post" in your html submit form. If you're already doing that , please post some code.

Comment: It was because of a maxPostSize parameter in Server.xml. It was set to 0

Comment: Also maxPostSize for me! thanks Rache.  Seems like tomcat 8 configs have changed; if you want unlimited post size - you now need to use -1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was because of the `maxPostSize` parameter in `Server.xml`.
It was set to 0. I have to use -1 instead of 0. Now it is working.